# Facebook Ads API Application does not have the capability to make this API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I see several other questions with similar descriptions but as far as I can tell my situation is different. I'm trying to make a Marketing API call to this url:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/{act_id}?fields=campaigns.limit(100){name,created_time}](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/%7Bact_id%7D?fields=campaigns.limit(100)%7Bname,created_time%7D)

I am using an access token that has been granted these scopes: `read_insights, manage_pages, pages_show_list, ads_read, public_profile`

The account id in this case has been added to FB Marketing API settings for this test version of my app (and even the production one to be 100% sure). The FB user has also been added as a tester.

This API call works fine in the vast majority of cases, but in certain scenarios I'll get a `Application does not have the capability to make this API call` error. If I log in with my own account everything works fine. In testing with my wife's FB account I get this error every time. It looks like any FB user has a default ads account called by their name and that's the one I'm trying to make the API call to.

I'm pretty stumped here, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also getting this, but only for a test account. With a production account I can make calls just fine.